# VSCode terminal wont says name is not defined for a basic command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/govH9.png)I kept following a tutorial for using vscode so I can learn python but this popped up when the same exact thing worked easy for the guy in the tutorial. Please help. I had to switch code extension terminal to on because I couldn't type in the output then this happened with the input command.

Comment: Even thought the IDE shows Python 3.11.4, the error indicates that you are running Python 2.

Comment: @KlausD. hey thanks for replying fast. could that be the reason behind the error? how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you might’ve forgotten to save your file.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](/q/21122540/4518341)

Comment: @cwbusacker i saved it now still wont work...

Comment: @wjandrea this works you helped a ton turns out i somehow really am running 2 versions but now i have to start my scripts with #!/usr/bin/env python3 so it works normally

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips for the future. It helps to provide text as text, [not a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), though the screenshot is fine for illustration.